# Azure Devops checkmark and cross symbol

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any way to manually enter green check mark and a red cross as an in line text symbol within azure devops?

Much like you can do in jira or confluence using the following keyboard shortcuts:

(/) or (x)

Answer (score 2):

In common, we are using [Markdown syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) to add symbol in a text field in Azure DevOps.

But Markdown does not support color: green, red.

As a work around, you could consider using [emoji](https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet)

It works well in both WIT discussion and Wiki page in Azure DevOps.

[image]

[image]